# How to know that Image is successfully loaded in Picturebox from the Internet?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-2.0, picturebox

I am using "ImageLocation" property of PictuerBox to get a picture from the web.

```
PB1.ImageLocation = "http://www.example.com/picture.png"
```

Some times the image which has to load in picture box from web is very large in size and can not be appear instantly in PictureBox. I need to conform that Image has successfully loaded in Picturebox, before performing next operation.
I have to Enable some controls just after loading of image from web.

Is there any way to conform this?
(Note: My PictureBox has an initial image also.)

Comment: Gimme a minute and I will come up with some code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [PictureBox.LoadCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.loadcompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

Comment: As I describe, My Picturebox also has an initial image which has to display until the large Image from the internet loaded.
Picturebox.LoadComplete event enabling my controls at initial image successfully load.
Now How to differentiate Initial Image and Internet Image :(

Comment: A variable jumps to mind.  Set it to True when you call Load().

Comment: Oh Yes variable will work. It's solve.
1 more question if we can check it in LoadComplete Event like that?
    If Not PB.Image = PB.InitialImage Then Button1.enable = true
It should be better :).

Answer (score 0):

Okay see what I did for mine was just download the picture. The image normally takes a while to start getting put into the picture box.

Here is my code:

```
If (My.Computer.FileExists("http://www.example.com/picture.png")) Then
  My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://www.example.com/picture.png", <Some Location>)
  PB1.ImageLocation = <Some location>
 Else
  End
End If
```

It may not be the most efficient way - but I can see it as a simple way of making it work.

Dunno if it's working or not, can't access Visual Studio at the moment

Comment: Hmm, Thank you for your answer @nfell2009 But It's not a solution it's a trick and we already known this.
The better one is "PictureBox.LoadCompleted" event.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why your code doesn't work.

EDIT: Because I've used that before and had no problems...